# Can't connect to an SSL LDAP server

Tags: ssl, erlang, ldap

I'm trying to connect to an LDAP server which is only available over ssl. When I try the following :

```
eldap:open([HOST], [{port, 636},{ssl, true}]).
```

I get the error

```
SSL: certify: ssl_handshake.erl:239:Fatal error: certificate unknown
{error,"connect failed"}
```

Does anybody has an idea to connect to a LDAP server over SSL in erlang?

P.S.:

Now, I am trying to use `stunnel`, but this won't work, too.

Comment: Most likely, the cause is that you don't have the root certificate (or the certificate itself) in your certificate store.

Comment: I also thought that this is the reason, but you can't configure your cacertfile when using eldap. Do you know, if there is a global erlang cacerts store like the key - or truststore in java?

Comment: @Ulf are you started crypto, public_key and ssl applications before eldap:open?

Comment: Yes, i started the chain. Now i think, that this is not a problem of eldap, but the ssl implementation. When i try to connect from the shell: sl:connect(HOST, 636, [{verify, verify_none}]).
i also get the error. I am using RB1503 64Bit on OSX

Answer (score 0):

Only for information.

The problem was that i got a certificate from my provider which was not valid. After fixing the certificate everything works fine.